# rand() function in c++

Tags: c++, c

i am not quite sure how this function in c++ works:

```
int rand_0toN1(int n) {
    return rand() % n;
}
```

Another tutorial on internet says to get a random number between a range you need to do something different however, with a being first number in range and n is number of terms in range:

```
int number = a + rand( ) % n;
```

I have read that it is supposed to return a random number between the value of 0 and n-1, but how does it do that? I understand that % means divide and give the remainder (so 5 % 2 would be 1) but how does that end up giving a number between 0 and n-1? Thanks for help in understanding this. I guess i don't understand what the rand() function returns.

Comment: `rand` returns random integer in range `0..RAND_MAX`. For the rest, write down a few examples with modulo on paper to see how it works. `man 3 rand` might help as well.

Comment: Note that unless n is a power of 2, this code does not produce a uniform distribution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885367/c-random-numbers)

Comment: @Nemo: However, for values of N between 20 and 1638, the distribution is _fairly_ uniform.  For this range, (the most likely number) is more likely than (the least likely number) by less than 5%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modulo (remainder) of division by *n* > 0 is always in the range [0, *n*); that's a basic property of modular arithmetic.

`a + rand() % n` does not return a number in the range [0, *n*) unless *a*=0; it returns an `int` in the range [*a*, *n* + *a*).

Note that this trick does *not* in general return [uniformly distributed integers](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html).

Comment: You mean not very random, because it uses time as seed?

Comment: And the way to get a proper distribution is?

Comment: No, I mean that it does not always generate according to a [uniform distribution](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29).

Comment: @Daniel Gratz: Nobody said "not very random". The distribution is not even. rand()%3. Probability of 0(10923/32767) 1(10922/32767) 2(10922/32767). Notice that 0 has a slightly higher probability.

Comment: @larsmans: You already have my +1. Just put the link in your answer so it is easy to see immediately.

Answer (score 4):

`rand` returns a pseudorandom value bewtween `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is usually `32767`.

The modulo operator is useful for "wrapping around" values:

```
0 % 5 == 0
1 % 5 == 1
2 % 5 == 2
3 % 5 == 3
4 % 5 == 4
5 % 5 == 0 // oh dear!
6 % 1 == 1
// etc...
```

As such, by combining that pseudorandom value with a modulo, you're getting a pseudorandom value that's guaranteed to be between `0` and `n - 1` inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

According to your own example, you seems to understand how it works.

`rand()` just returns an integer pseudorandom number between 0 and RAND_MAX, **then** you apply the modulo operator to that number. Since the modulo operator returns the remainder of division of one number by another, a number divided by N will always return a number lesser than N.

Answer (score 0):

The `rand()` function returns an integral value in the interval
`[0...RAND_MAX]`.  And the results of `x % n` will always be in the
range `[0...n)` (provided `x >= 0`, at least); this is basic math.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

Usually you "seed" it with the time function. And then use the modulus operator to specify a range.

Comment: I am getting annoyed at that misinformation appearing all the time. Read: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Answer (score 0):

The c++ rand() function gives you a number from 0 to RAND_MAX (a constant defined in `<cstdlib>`), which is at least 32767. ([from the c++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/))

The modulus (%) operator gives the remainder after dividing.  When you use it with rand() you are using it to set an upper limit (n) on what the random number can be.

For example, lets say you wanted a number between 0 and 4.  Calling rand() will give you an answer between 0 and 32767.  rand() % 5, however, will force the remainder to be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on the value rand() returned (if rand() returned 10, 10%5 = 0; if it returned 11, 11%5 = 0, etc.).

Comment: Don't imply that cplusplus.com is an authoritative source on C++ ("**the** C++ documentation" implies authorativness) it is full of bad things (nice for quick reference though). But that link keeps popping up and it irritates my how bad the advice is. Read http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html